# circle arc proof

Tags: geometry

[image]

I have this picture and I have to show angle phi is equal to angle theta and I can assume both circles are the same. I'm having trouble getting started.I know that there are congruent line segments but that doesn't mean the arcs are of the same measure too or does it. Basically arcs CD and WZ for example?

Comment: In general for two points $A$ and $B$ on a circle, the length of arc $AB$ determines and is determined by the length of chord $AB$.

Comment: I figured but problem is I can't use that since we haven't covered that.

Comment: You can derive this in five lines or so. It's a quick result. Hint: if on a general circle, chords $AB=A'B'$, show that $\Delta ABO$ and $\Delta A'B'O$ are congruent trianlges.

Comment: So vertical angles?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the theorem about [Interior angles to circle](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/geometry/circle/angles-of-intersecting-chords-theorem.php) , then check the following hints:

1) In a circle, cords with the same length intercept equal arcs  and thus , for example $\,\widehat{AB}=\widehat{XY}\,$

2) An interior angle equals the semisum of the two arcs its legs intercept, so for example

$$\phi=\frac{1}{2}\left(\widehat{AB}+\widehat{CD}\right)$$

Now prove your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

$\theta = \angle DAC + \angle BDA=\frac12 \angle DOC+\frac12BOA$ ad the "same" holds for the orther circle

Comment: I got it. Basically using the property that chords are congruent iff they subtend congruent arcs. I apparently skipped over that property in the book.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Have you heard about [inscribed angles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle)?

[image: circle-angle]

Good luck!